# Can't connect chrome cast with dlink 600L

Tags: networking, router, chromecast

My chrome cast shows up fine and is easy to set up until it tries to connect with the wifi in which case there is an issue. I have tried to go into the network settings to enable the network and allow multicasting, however cannot find these features… Is it possible that the router just will not work with the chrome cast at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would leave this as a comment but don't yet have the reputation so I'll try to provide an answer instead.

Your router should almost definitely be able to support chromecast as there are some forum posts out there indicating chromecast works with it (http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=59323.0 for one)

The first step I'd recommend is to see if there are settings which say 'network isolation' or 'create separate vlans for each client' - these will prevent chromecast from working properly.

The second step I'd recommend is to see if you can use a cellphone hotspot or friends wifi to hookup your chromecast as some forums suggest that updates to the chromecast fixed issues with some networking hardware.

Try those and report back with more details? Most importantly, if you could tell us some of the network settings from your router we will be able to diagnose more.

(Sorry again for using the answer field)